# Parse.com: Include nested pointers in compound query.or()

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have the following structure in my app:

```
Messages -> receiver-> User (User.username)
            sender -> User (User.username)
```

where the -> represent a pointer. I want to get all the messages **sent** from the current user to their intended Receiver. And the messages **received** by the
current user in order to create a conversation summary.

The problem is that **The receiver username is always empty** on the query, while sender username is fine.
How can I get the username of the receiver?

```
var Receiver = new Parse.User();
Receiver.id = 'XXXXXX'; // the problem seems to be here, why???
// Query messages sent by current user
var senderQuery = new Parse.Query(MyParseMessage);
senderQuery.equalTo("receiver", Receiver);
senderQuery.equalTo("sender", Parse.User.current());

// Query messages sent by other user
var receiverQuery = new Parse.Query(MyParseMessage);
receiverQuery.equalTo("receiver", Parse.User.current());
receiverQuery.equalTo("sender", Receiver);

// Combined Query with OR condition
var messageQuery = Parse.Query.or(senderQuery, receiverQuery);
// this should include the receiver data
receiverQuery.include('receiver'); // this is not working, why is not working?

messageQuery.find();
```

What am I missing? thanks!

Comment: javascript doesn't have [pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28programming%29). Which language are you really using? Or, can you rephrase to not use words that have a well-defined meaning in programming but you're using to mean something else?

Comment: It is a pointer in Parse.com, thanks for your answer.

Comment: .include('receiver'); Needs to be on the messageQuery query. Updated code below

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix this I did something weird: I had to go to Parse then find the User Object and then make the query I wanted:

```
var deferral = $q.defer();
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("objectId", receiverId);
query.find().then(function (user) {
// Query messages sent by current user
    var senderQuery = new Parse.Query(MyParseMessage);
    senderQuery.equalTo("receiver", user[0]);
    senderQuery.equalTo("sender", Parse.User.current());

// Query messages sent by other user
    var receiverQuery = new Parse.Query(MyParseMessage);
    receiverQuery.equalTo("receiver", Parse.User.current());
    receiverQuery.equalTo("sender", user[0]);

// Combined Query with OR condition
    var messageQuery = Parse.Query.or(senderQuery, receiverQuery);
// this should include the receiver data
    receiverQuery.include('receiver'); 

    return deferral.resolve(messageQuery.find());
});
return deferral.promise;
```

Answer (score 0):

`.include('receiver');` was moved to the `messageQuery` query

```
  var Receiver = new Parse.User();
    Receiver.id = 'XXXXXX'; // the problem seems to be here, why???
    // Query messages sent by current user
    var senderQuery = new Parse.Query(MyParseMessage);
    senderQuery.equalTo("receiver", Receiver);
    senderQuery.equalTo("sender", Parse.User.current());
    
    // Query messages sent by other user
    var receiverQuery = new Parse.Query(MyParseMessage);
    receiverQuery.equalTo("receiver", Parse.User.current());
    receiverQuery.equalTo("sender", Receiver);
    
    // Combined Query with OR condition
    var messageQuery = Parse.Query.or(senderQuery, receiverQuery);
    // this should include the receiver data
    messageQuery.include('receiver'); // this is not working, why is not working?
    
    messageQuery.find();
```